# Family prolog Exercise

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I don't know how to solve this. I have to write a siblings rule. All the way at the bottom of the code I have my siblings rule. The problem with the rule is that it returns the siblings twice. For example, if I want to get julia's siblings, I get "rosa" twice. I suppose that what is happening is that the program evaluates for each parent (alex and lina). So how could I fix my rule so I only get julia's (or anyone's) siblings just once?

```
parent(alex,julia).
parent(alex,rosa).
parent(lina,julia).
parent(lina,rosa).
parent(romeo,peter).
parent(julia,peter).
parent(rosa,silvia).
parent(oscar,ida).
parent(eva,ida).
parent(eva,bruno).
parent(peter,bruno).
parent(peter,georg).
parent(peter,irma).
parent(ruth,georg).
parent(ruth,irma).
parent(silvia,otto).
parent(silvia,pascal).
parent(irma,olga).
parent(irma,jean).
parent(otto,olga).
parent(otto,jean).
parent(jean,tina).
parent(marie,tina).

male(alex).
male(romeo).
male(oscar).
male(peter).
male(bruno).
male(georg).
male(otto).
male(pascal).
male(jean).


husband(alex,lina).
husband(romeo,julia).
husband(oscar,eva).
husband(peter,ruth).
husband(otto,irma).
husband(jean,marie).

% father(X,Y) :- X is the father of Y.

father(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y), male(X).

% grandfather(X,Y) :- X is the grandfather of Y.

grandfather(X,Y) :- father(X,P), parent(P,Y).

% brother(X,Y) :- X is the brother of Y.

brother(X,Y) :- parent(P,X), parent(P,Y), male(X), X \= Y.

% uncle(X,Y) :- X is the uncle of Y.

uncle(X,Y) :- brother(X,P), parent(P,Y).

% female(X) :- X is a female person.

female(X) :- \+ male(X).

% sister(X,Y) :- X is the sister of Y.

sister(X,Y) :- parent(P,X), parent(P,Y), female(X), X \= Y.

% has_son(X) :- the person X has a son.

has_son(X) :- parent(X,Y), male(Y).

% married(X,Y) :- X and Y are married to each other.

married(X,Y) :- husband(X,Y).
married(X,Y) :- husband(Y,X).

% brother_in_law(X,Y) :- X is the brother-in-law of Y.

brother_in_law(X,Y) :- brother(X,P), married(P,Y).
brother_in_law(X,Y) :- husband(X,W), sister(W,Y).

% ancestor(X,Y) :- X is an ancestor of Y.

ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,P), ancestor(P,Y).

% relatives(X,Y) :- X and Y are relatives (related by blood to each other).

relatives(X,X).
relatives(X,Y) :- ancestor(X,Y).
relatives(X,Y) :- ancestor(Y,X).
relatives(X,Y) :- ancestor(A,X), ancestor(A,Y).

% ancestors(As,X) :- As is the set of all (known) ancestors of X.

ancestors(As,X) :- setof(A,ancestor(A,X),As).

% descendants(Ds,X) :- Ds is the set of all (known) descendants of X.

descendants(Ds,X) :-setof(D,ancestor(X,D),Ds).

% ancestor(X,Y,L) :- X is an ancestor of Y, and L is the list of names
% leading from X to Y.

ancestor(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y,[X|L]) :- parent(X,P), ancestor(P,Y,L).


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Exercise 1
% Write a rule that determines if mother (M) is mother of (C) child.
% mother(M, C) :-

mother(M,C) :- female(M), parent(M,C).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Exercise 2
% Write a rule that infers the siblings of certain (X) person
% siblings. Ss is the siblings list.
% siblings(Ss, X) :-

sibling(X,Y) :- dif(X,Y),parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).
```

Comment: Use `mother/2` and/or `father/2` to make the predicate "assymetrical" (given of course same-sex marriages are *not* allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is **correct**. The problem with your predicate is that a person has (normally) two parents: a `mother/2` and a `father/2`.

That means that if `rosa` and `julia` are (*real*) siblings (then they share the same `mother/2` and `father/2`).

If we `trace.` we see that this orginates in the duplication:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- sibling(rosa, julia).
   Call: (8) sibling(rosa, julia) ? creep
   Call: (9) dif:dif(rosa, julia) ? creep
   Exit: (9) dif:dif(rosa, julia) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(_5278, rosa) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(alex, rosa) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(alex, julia) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(alex, julia) ? creep
   Exit: (8) sibling(rosa, julia) ? creep
true ;
   Redo: (9) parent(alex, julia) ? creep
   Fail: (9) parent(alex, julia) ? creep
   Redo: (9) parent(_5278, rosa) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(lina, rosa) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(lina, julia) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(lina, julia) ? creep
   Exit: (8) sibling(rosa, julia) ? creep
true.
```

So first we find a `sibling/2` relation through `alex` (the `father/2` of the two), and later we find the `sibling/2` relation through `lina` (the `mother/2` of the two).

If there are no *half*-siblings here (two persons sharing the same `father/2` or `mother/2`, but not the same `mother/2` or `father/2`), then we can "deduplicate" this by picking only one of the two parents, for example the `mother/2`:

```
sibling(A, B) :-
    dif(A, B),
    mother(M, A),
    mother(M, B).
```

Based on the comment, it appears that your `female/1` predicate is not working properly. So I propose you try to fix this.

or through a `father/2`:

```
sibling(A, B) :-
    dif(A, B),
    father(F, A),
    father(F, B).
```

In case we consider a family with half-siblings, we can implement a predicate where we consider a `sibling/2` by checking both the `mother/2` and `father/2`.

Comment: Right now I'm not considering half-siblings so what you said makes perfect sense but when I try and get julia's siblings by sibling(A, julia). It returns false, any idea why?

Comment: @JorgePadilla: yes, your `female(X)` predicate fails if `X` is a free variable.

Comment: You can also fix the `mother/2` predicate, by first specifying `parent(M, C)` and then `female(M)`, since then `M` is "unified" with a constant before checking `female/1`.

Comment: OK thanks, I've reordered the parent/mother thing and I came up with this: siblings(Ss, X) :- dif(Ss, X), father(F, Ss), father(F, X), mother(M, Ss), mother(M, X). Does it make sense at all? Or do you notice something buggy?